# Git -- Is it possible create a repository placeholder?

Tags: git, git-clone

I know that you can run `git clone -n git@repo` to clone without checking out files, but is it possible to clone a repository without even pulling the refs?

For example, if I had a repository that I wanted to create a placeholder for I could this:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git remote add origin git@repo
```

Then everything would be in place so that I could pull at a later date.

Comment: And yeah, I know that I could write a script for this. But in the interest of laziness I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: I don't know of any better answer than the one you already provided.

Comment: You can skip `mkdir` and do `git init repo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only can add some initialization config steps like:

```
git init repo
cd repo
git remote add origin git@repo

git config user.name yourName
git config user.email yourEmail
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

*Then* everything would be ready for a git fetch.

This is similar to this Gist script "[`remgit.sh`](https://gist.github.com/ckalima/1364886)"